# Scraping html headers in R using XML package

Tags: html, xml, r, screen-scraping

I'm trying to extract the header 1 (h1) from a html code like this:

```
<div class="cuerpo-not"><div mod="2323">
<h1>Jamón 5 Jotas, champagne Bollinger y King Alexander III</h1>
```

I'm using the function `xpathSApply()` but it returns nothing:

```
xpathSApply(webpage, "//div[contains(@class, 'cuerpo-not')]/h1", xmlValue)
# list()
```

But when I use the same function without specify the class of header, it returns all the information below the class in this format:

```
xpathSApply(webpage, "//div[contains(@class, 'cuerpo-not')]", xmlValue)

# ;\n\t\t}\n\t}\n\t\n\t\n\tenviarNoticiaLeida_Site( 6916437,16 ) ;\n//]]>Jamón 5 Jotas, champagne Bollinger y King Alexander III\n\n\n\tPor J.M.
```

How can I extract the information as a string? In other web pages the previous code has worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need one more `/` in your query down to `h1`, as in `//h1` instead of `/h1`.

```
library(XML)

x <- '<div class="cuerpo-not"><div mod="2323">
<h1>Jamón 5 Jotas, champagne Bollinger y King Alexander III</h1>'

xpathSApply(htmlParse(x), "//div[contains(@class, 'cuerpo-not')]//h1", xmlValue)
# [1] "JamÃ³n 5 Jotas, champagne Bollinger y King Alexander III"
```